# Django Error - Product Does Not Exist when clicking Buy button for first item in cart (If you have more than one product it works)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I'm a Django beginner working on a Django shopping website. When a user clicks the "Buy" button for a product, it should create an order and remove the product from the cart.

However, I'm encountering an issue where I get a **`DoesNotExist`** error when trying to buy the first product that is added to the cart (If i add two products then it works). The error says "No Product matches the given query." and it is raised by the **`placeOrder`** view.

This error only occurs for the first product that is added to the cart. If I add more products to the cart, I can buy them without any issues.

I've checked the database and the product IDs are correct. I've also tried clearing the session and cache but it didn't resolve the issue.

**views.py**

```
def placeOrder(request, product_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Retrieve the product based on the id
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

        # Retrieve the customer based on the current user
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=request.user)

        # Create a new Order with the product and customer
        Order.objects.create(product=product, customer=customer, status='PENDING')

        # Get the user's cart and remove the product from it
        cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cart.products.remove(product)

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        # Get or create the user's cart
        cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'cart': cart,
        }
        return render(request, 'website/placeOrder.html', context)
```

urls.py -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from website import views
from website.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('placeOrder/<int:i>/', views.placeOrder, name='placeOrder'),
    path('login/', loginPage, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logoutPage, name='logout'),
    path('register/', registerPage, name='register'),
    path('addProduct/', addProduct, name='addProduct'),
    path('add_to_cart/<int:product_id>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py -**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

placeOrder.html (cart) -

```
{% extends 'website/dependencies.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron container row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">
           <form action="" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <br>
               {% for product in cart.products.all %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; border:5px black solid">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{product.description}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{product.price}}</p>
            <form action="{% url 'placeOrder' product.id %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="submit" value="Buy">
                    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}


               <p>This is your cart. (If you cannot see anything that is because you haven't added anything to cart)</p>

             </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I was expecting that when the 'Buy' button is clicked for a product, a new **`Order`** would be created for the corresponding product and customer, the product would then be removed from the cart, and the user would be redirected to the homepage.

However, the expected behavior only happens from the second product onwards that is added to the cart. For the first product, it raises a **`DoesNotExist`** error.

This is the screenshot of the error -
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1gRZ.png)

Please comment if you need any other file

Comment: Please show your method createproductform() under the addProduct view

Comment: class createproductform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).